# VBA Excel prompt user to select a file in a default folder

Tags: vba, excel, directory, default

I would like to prompt user to open an Excel file in a default folder. I don't know how to open a default folder.

```
Sub Program1()
    DefaultFolder = "C:\user\dump"
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FName <> False Then
        Set WorkB2 = Workbooks.Open(FName)
        ' some codes here
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use chdir:

```
Sub Program1()
  Chdir "C:\user\dump"
  FName = Application.GetOpenFilename
  If FName <> False Then
    Set WorkB2 = Workbooks.Open(FName)
    ' some codes here
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example to open excel file

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpenFile()
    Dim xlFile      As Variant

    ChDir "C:\temp"

    '// Showing Excel Dialog
    xlFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Excel Files (*.xls*)," & _
    "*.xls*", 1, "Select Excel File", "Open", False)

    '// If Cancel then exit
    If TypeName(xlFile) = "Boolean" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '// Open selected file
    Workbooks.Open xlFile
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that was not the question. "I would like to prompt user to open an Excel file **in a default folder**." If I understand correctly, he is looking for a way to set the default folder. Look at his attempt in the code: `DefaultFolder = "C:\user\dump"`

Comment: grrr i think i need to get coffe my mistake @vacip

Comment: I'm happy u mentioned this method, I have never used `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)`, so I'll give it a go next time. :)

Comment: @vacip your wellcome i like your answer +1